# Python ASCII character's in path names

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, windows-8, path

I am writing a simple encryption program that encrypts string and the file name using `ord()` and `chr()` but every time I try writing it to a file using `file()`, IDLE raises:

```
IOError... invalid mode or filename: "\xf6Z\x13Q\xdbG!\n\x0f.txt"
```

When I use `print()`, it shows the actual symbols, but when writing it uses the literal string confusing python.

Note: I am encrypting one file and placing the encrypted file in a new directory. I tried using `os.path.join()` and `.abspath()` but only works on the relative directory.

I noticed it'll work if I am not using absolute path names and just the file name, but since I have to use two different locations I must use absolute.

```
enc_file_name  = encrypt('MyFile.txt')
f.write(enc_file_name, some_string)
```

Any ideas on how to manipulate the path name for two paths?

Comment: Why do you want such weird filenames? IIRC, Windows doesn't permit filenames to contain a newline character. It's possible to encrypt filenames, but to keep things manageable the encrypted names should just use printable characters. Using ASCII would be simplest, although you can use UTF-8 if you know what you're doing...

Comment: Can you give a minimal working example? You are probably entering invalid characters, or you are not correctly encoding the filename.

Comment: I can give an example, but the point is to have the weird file name. It works with relative file directories, but when I have to work with two directories, I have to use absolute. Like you can easily write that weird string to a filename, but python gets confused when you try pointing it outside the current dicrectory. It makes since if you dealt with Vigenere Ciphers or any other encryption methods in general.